# What does "?" mean in the parameters of a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was searching for an solution for getting the greatest prime factor of a number and found a script that works, but there is a `?` (Question Mark) in the `for` loop.  I was wondering what the `?` does?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    n=317584931803;
    for(i=2;n>1;n%i?i++:(n/=i,document.write(i+' ')));
</script>
```

And, if you can also explain what exactly this script does, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The `?` and `:` together form the JavaScript Conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: I hope there is a special place in hell for people who write code like that -_- so unreadable

Comment: That is actually evil.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'll assume you've never encountered [Duff's Device](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/duffs-device.html) before.

Comment: What does that mean n/=i

Comment: @MinaGabriel: `n/=i;` is `n = n / i;` Just like `n = n + i` can be written as `n+=i;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's known as the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Basically, `x ? y : z` means if `x` is true, evaluate and return `y`, otherwise evaluate and return `z`. In this way, it's like an inline `if/else`-statement.

In this case we can break down your code like this:

```
n=317584931803;
for(i=2;n>1;n%i?i++:(n/=i,document.write(i+' ')));
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var n=317584931803;
for (var i=2; n>1; n % i ? i++ : (n /= i, document.write(i + ' '))) {
    // do nothing
}
```

But this `for` loop can be written more clearly as a `while` loop:

```
var n=317584931803, i = 2;
while (n > 1) {
    n % i ? i++ : (n /= i, document.write(i + ' ');
}
```

And the conditional operator can be expanded to:

```
var n=317584931803, i = 2;
while (n > 1) {
    if (n % i > 0) {
        i++;
    } else {
        n = n / i;
        document.write( i + ' ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its called [Conditional Operator (?:)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Complete Expression is

```
 test ? expression1 : expression2
```

Here if `test` condition is true, `expression1` will be evaluated otherwise `expression2`

This is your expression

```
 n % i ? i++ : (n /= i, document.write(i + ' '))
```

Comment: Please **stop** calling it a "ternary" operator.

Comment: @zerkms But it IS a ternary operator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

Comment: @zerkms - why? If I look up `ternary` it returns this exact construct as an example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: @KevinDTimm: "Since this operator is often the only existing ...". You don't call `++` an unary operator don't you?

Comment: @Justin Warkentin: when another ternary operator will be introduced in a language you'll experience a lot of issues with terminology. Why not follow the correct naming from the very beginning?

Comment: @zerkms - Yeah, when there's only one of something, normal humans refer to that thing as though there's only one of that thing. It's not that weird.

Comment: @lwburk: "normal" is subjective. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/18/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary.aspx

Comment: @zerkms Regardless, it is widely known as and called "the ternary operator". So far, I'm not aware of any other ternary operators. When that magical day comes in a popular language, I'm sure we'll differentiate them with their proper names. Technically "conditional operator" isn't really that explicit either.

Comment: @Justin Warkentin: it is explicit since it's assigned in an unique manner to a `?:` language (syntax) construction.

Comment: Yes, it's also my subjective opinion that you're being silly.

Comment: @lwburk: that's not polite. Anyway, if one doesn't want to use a proper name - it's their business. Please continue spreading a bs, amen.

Comment: @zerkms Just out of curiosity, are you aware of any language which has more than one ternary operator?

Comment: @p.s.w.g: not of any I work with every day. Haven't made any research on that, but if it's that important it's not that difficult to provide a BNF for the language that would provide 2 ternary operators. Or a single ternary operator that doesn't behave like in another languages.

Comment: Please refer to *the* President of the United States as *a* President of the United States, because, theoretically, we could add a second president at some point.

Comment: @lwburk: okay, I will. Now your turn to start using proper names.

Comment: @lwburk: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12 you're welcome. Not even a **SINGLE WORD** about "ternary" in the whole specification. Any further questions?

Comment: You're confused about how language works. I use sounds and symbols to unambiguously refer to things for the benefit of other humans. I never claimed to be quoting a spec. I also don't see the words "immediately invoked function expression" anywhere in the spec. Or even the word module. We name things outside the confines of the spec *all the time*.

Comment: This reminds me of one time when I used the word *context* in its normal English sense and somebody yelled at me because *context* wasn't in the spec. I had to explain that I was just using English to describe something. Programmers can be weird about this stuff.

Comment: @lwburk: 1. It is defined by specification, I don't see any reason to not use the official (see "proper") name 2. The specification doesn't define IIFE just because it's not a single language construct - it's a function expression followed by a function invocation. "We name things outside the confines of the spec all the time" --- it's a science. It's a good idea to use the terms that are defined in a trustable source. Otherwise one day you'll advocate using "that thing" instead of "IIFE"